# Synchronizing data from QField to original SpatiaLite database

Tags: qgis, qfield

I'm trying to get started with QField. I created a SpatiaLite database with several SpatiaLite layers in my QGIS project. Exporting that project with QFieldSync is super easy, as is (offline) editing the data in QFIELD on my tablet. When I import and synchronize the data back to my QGIS project all the data is there and everything seems fine. However, the source path of the SpatiaLite layers has changed:

Original path: `C:\Users\...\Documents\Demo.sqlite`

Path after synchronization: `C:\Users\...\QField\import\demo2\Demo.sqlite`

The original data is thus not synchronized, instead a new file with the same name but in a different location is created.

My questions are:

Is this supposed to happen?

If yes, what is a smooth way to make sure the original data gets updated as well?

If no, what should I do differently?

Comment: is the QFieldSync plugin used? https://www.line-45.com/labs/QGIS-QField.pdf 'syncronized from Qfield' (Note:Geopackage is recommended)

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, go to the tab "Plugins" -> QFieldSync -> Preferences. Here you can change the default import  location.

To sync data back from your mobile device, you need to open the original project in QGIS and then sync it with the plugin.

If it is still not working, you may report the issue directly to the developers in [GitHub](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues)

Comment: I changed from SpatiaLite to GeoPackage and the problem seems solved.